# I don't think we should block [ads], but let's talk about them

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

Looking at the [ads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ads) tag, it seems quite abused and often a meta-tag, but there seems valid usages like... well, I can't quite find one right now, but 192 watchers and 2.1k questions suggests people find it useful, although I doubt if anyone can be an expert in all the advert APIs, for instance.

There are a number of more specific tags like [admob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/admob) and [adsense-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adsense-api) and [facebook-ads-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-ads-api), so in theory [ads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ads) is redundant, but does it need to die? I don't have the answer, but I rate it as two "Yes"s and two "Probably"s on [the burnination scale](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191) so it probably should live despite me not liking it.

<sup>It's also got a useless guidance summary of "Ads is an abbreviation for Advertisements.", but I've submitted an edit for that.</sup>

Comment: I lean toward keeping it because the number of ad providers is large enough that we can't have more specific tags for all of them, and less commonly used providers probably don't really need a separate tag anyway.

Comment: Not a great tag.  What meaningful information does it impart in a programming context?  Compare with, say the C# tag or the SQL tag.

Comment: I was going to say "but what if your ad network/API doesn't have a tag?" but then I remembered we can create tags. I too see no reason -- it's less like a C# or SQL tag and more like a "programming" tag. I can't think of any on-topic question that wouldn't be about a specific API and would merit this tag (in addition to the api tag).

Comment: Note, following a tag just mean that questions are more likely to appear on your homepage, it doesn't affect any other functionality of the site (except when you search for intags:mine). Now, if the tags you follow appear intermingled in your /tag/new or /tag/active view, I would assure you that many people would follow less tags than they do today.